# Game objects all blue underneath

Tags: unity, shaders, materials

I have an empty scene with a single object in it, a cube.

The cube renders initially as pink, when it has no material attached.

[image]

When I attach a material though.  Any material.  Odd things happen.

I have created some extremely basic materials, which are just colours.  Some metallic, some not.  If I apply when of these the cube does not go the colour expected.  The exception of this is the Green and Blue materials, although I suspect they're the wrong shade.

Please see below:

[image]

Why could this be happening?  My settings look pretty standard on the cube...

[image]

If I create a brand new cube and set the materials up the exact same thing happens.

I have downloaded some sample materials from the asset store, and they behave strangely too.  A brown wood/bark texture does the following:

[image]

And here is that texture, definitely no sign of blue.

[image]

There are no lights set up, and the cube is the only item live on the scene, everything else is switched off.

I have also added a camera and rendered the scene.  Same thing.

[image]

Is there some sort of ambient light setting or something I am missing quite obvious?  Really not sure what to do here.

Comment: Do you have any lights in the scene?

Comment: This looks like the default bluish ambient light. What's in your [lighting settings window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html)?  If you don't want your materials to be affected by the lighting setup, have you considered using unlit materials?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, feel free to add an Answer so other users can learn from your experience.